# Moving sphere gameObject between 3 points in a loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am defining three gameObject points where a sphere gameObject should travel from one position to another in a loop, such that 1-2-3-1-2-3....(as in a triangle). I am able to achieve the movement with `Vector3.MoveTowards()` function but it only takes in 2 points. Is there a way to achieve the same with multiple points? (atleast 3 or more)

```
public class SlideBetweenPoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform pointA, pointB, pointC;
    public float speed;
 
     void Update ()
     {
        float step =  speed * Time.deltaTime; 
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(pointA.position , pointB.position , step);
 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes simply move towards one point and when you reached it go to the next one.

Note that currently you are always starting again from `pointA`. In order to continuously move towards a target position you have to  rather use

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, step);
```

I would rather use a more general List like

```
public class SlideBetweenPoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> points;
    public float speed;
 
    private int index;

     void Update ()
     { 
         transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, points[index].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
 
         if(transform.position == points[index].position)
         {
             // increase index with wrap around
             index = (index + 1) % points.Count;
         }
     }
}
```

Where `transform.position == points[index]` uses a precision of `1e-5` for equality. If you really need it you could also check for exact matching positions:

```
 if(Mathf.Approximately(0, (transform.position- points[index].position).sqrMagnitude))
 {
     index = (index + 1) % points.Count;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! That is perfect! Exactly what i was looking for.